# Auto Importing Using Statements in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, namespaces, using-statement

In Visual Studio, when you see a red line, you can place your cursor over the word, press `Ctrl + .` and click on the namespace you want to import (via a `using` statement). Is there a way to do this in VS Code without memorizing the namespaces?

Comment: What programming language? Such has been added to extensions like the C# one, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1117 so other language extension developers should follow.

Comment: I'm using c#. I want to be able to easily add using statements.